# Powershell confusion about Variable

Tags: powershell, variables

I am confused regarding variables.

I have code, where I have the following line:

```
$search = $Name.SelectedItem.Split('-')[$($Name.SelectedItem.Split('-').Count-1)]+'*'
```

This line does nothing else, as split up a selected item (I am working with a Dropdownbox) and transfers it to $search.

The funny thing is, it does exactly that, what I want it to do.

When I type $search, the result can be for example:

Rue de Rivoli*

When I continue in the code and use $search through several arrays, for some reason, it does not function, because it does not find anything in a foreach loop. I have no error message and even the Rue de Rivoli* existing in one of the arrays, it does not find anything.

When I replace the above code and give directly the name to the variable $search, as seen below

```
$search = 'Rue de Rivoli*'
```

my search in the array works.

What am I missing here? I am doing something wrong, but I do not know what it is, can someone help me please to understand?

Thank you very much,

Mike

As requested, here more of the code. It is a lot to deal with, that is why I shorten it.

```
Clear-Host
$search = $CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem.Split('-')[$($CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem.Split('-').Count-1)]+'*'
#$search = 'Rue de Rivoli*'

$AllLocations = (get-variable -Include USPennsylvaniaAve, USSixthStreet, USRodeoDrive, USOneMicrosoftWay,`
                    USNorthTantauAvenue, USMarketStreet, USMainStreet, USEmilyDrive,`
                    USCalle8, USBroadway, US18thStreetNW, UKOxfordStreet, UKDowningStreet,`
                    UKBondStreet, FRRuedeRivoli, FRChampsElysees, CHBahnhofstrasse,`
                    CA17thAvenue) | ? {$_.value -is [array]}

Foreach ($Array in $AllLocations)
{
    if ($array.value -like $search)
    {break}
}
$result = "`$$($array.name)"
$result
```

This is about to become a function and does nothing else, as from the selecteditem, it takes it apart and add's the * behind it, so I can search
for a name with a wildcard.

I have several arrays and therefore I included only the necessary ones. Next step is to loop through the arrays and as soon as it found the item, it stops and gives the result to result.
This is my test code and it runs and does what I want, besides the line after Clear-Host. The code is correctly resolved and added to $search but does not work.
Below that code of line, I have my cheat line, where I add directly the correct result to the variable and it works fine.

Comment: Need more information on the array and show you piece of code to. Kindly edit the question and give all the necessary things.

Comment: Hello Ranadip, thank you, I can give the array, no problem but it is all part of large code, so it is too much, that is why I shorten it.

Comment: Yes, it is needed to understand your code too. So without the minimal verifiable code it is very difficult to isolate the issue.

Comment: Have you tried using `[-1]` to get the last variable instead of retyping it? Or using `$search = ... ; $search[$search.count-1]` There is nothing wrong with splitting that line into two sections to make it more readable. *just suggestion for the code, not the answer

Comment: OH and please forgive me. I am a totally greenhorn, when it comes to coding. This is a little project of mine and for any mistakes, please forgive me, I try to understand and follow the rules of coding but it is not that easy, lots of respect to all of you.

Comment: Hello Shadowzee,
The reason was, that I wanted to shorten it, because the content can be "France - Champs-Elysees" and I only want the last part, that is why I shortened it. At the end, it does not matter to me but I thought, on such way, less of a problem during a search.

Comment: @Mike Can you double check if `$array.value` actually stores anything? I wrote up a sample and the values are stored under `$array.values`. The autocomplete in powershell ise showed it as I was typing in value. You can use the `F9` key to place a breakpoint in powershell ISE and double check the values and run the commands when it hits it

Comment: @Shadowzee. Yes, it does store. I just checked.

Comment: @Shadowzee You are right, the problem is in the line with the $array.value, try to find a workaround, but so far no success.

Comment: If as you say hardcoding the `$search = 'Rue de Rivoli*'` works, I suspect your code does not take in account the fact that the split may return a value with whitespace around it. It would have helped if you have shown us the complete value of `$CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem`. Try `$search = ($CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem.Split('-')[-1]).Trim() + '*'`

Comment: @Theo WOW, you solved it. I bang my head against the wall, ha ha ha...I wasn't aware, there was a whitespace in it. I have to remember that but thinking about it, is makes sense.
Thank you so much, you saved my day

Comment: I have added this as answer to the question. I hope you don't mind. It is just because so many questions are answered in comments on SO. Leaving them that way looks like these questions never got answered because they are not accepted. An accepted answer is easier to find for others and as side effect it will also add to my rep ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, this should solve the problem.

<sup>(I'm adding this as answer too, so the OP can accept it. Otherwise this question will remain seemingly unsolved)</sup>

When hardcoding the search string `$search = 'Rue de Rivoli*'` works, but using a `Split()` to get the search string does not, then usually the string you obtain using the split is surrounded by whitespace characters. If you leave these in, the string will *appear* to look just fine, but when using as comparison it won't work.

If for instance the complete `$CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem` string is:

```
"François Exemple - Rue de Rivoli"
```

Then, using `$CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem.Split("-")[-1]` will return:

```
" Rue de Rivoli"
```

Note the space in front.

By simply performing a `Trim()` you will get rid of that space.

The line therefore should be:

```
$search = ($CreateNewUserFormDropDownBoxLocation.SelectedItem.Split('-')[-1]).Trim() + '*'
```

Comment: Actually, you can remove the comments since you have already posted it as answer. :)